# Verify if there is an empty input text/email/date with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning how to program so bear with me. I pretty much need to verify if there are empty spaces in a form that needs to be filled out, I'm using javascript. I did the following but for some reason even if I fill out all the spaces it still tells me that there are empty spaces.

(This his how the HMTML for each id looks like)

```
 <label for="txtNombre">Name</label>
 <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Name">

let inputName = document.querySelector('#txtName').value; 
let inputLastName = document.querySelector('#txtLastName').value; 
let inputPassword = document.querySelector('#txtPassword').value; 
let inputConfirm = document.querySelector('#txtConfirm').value; 
let inputDate = document.querySelector('#dDate').value;

function validateForm(){
    let bError = false;

    if(inputPassword === '' || inputConfirm === '' || inputName ==='' || inputLastName === '' || inputDate === ''){
        bError = true;
        showMessage(bError);
    }else if (inputPassword === inputConfirm) {
        inputPassword.classList.remove('borderError');
        showMessage(bError);
    } else{
        inputPassword.classList.add('borderError');
        bError = true;
        showMessage2(bError);
    }
}

function showMessage(pbError){
    divMessage.innerHTML = '';
    divMessage.classList.remove('error');
    divMessage.classList.remove('correct');

    let spanMessage = document.createElement('span');
    let nodeMessage;

    if(pbError === true){
        divMessage.classList.add('error');
        nodeMessage = document.createTextNode('Missing fields to be filled out');       
    }else{
        divMessage.classList.add('correcto');
        nodeMessage = document.createTextNode('Data saved');
    }

    spanMessage.appendChild(nodeMessage);
    divMessage.appendChild(spanMessage);
    divMessage.classList.remove('invisible');
}
```

Comment: `if(inputPassword === '' || inputConfirm === '' || inputName ==='' || inputLastName === '' || inputDate === ''){
    ` where are those variables defined?

Comment: Like this:

let inputName = document.querySelector('#txtName').value;
let inputLastName = document.querySelector('#txtLastName').value;
let inputPassword = document.querySelector('#txtPassword').value;
let inputConfirm = document.querySelector('#txtConfirm').value;
let inputDate = document.querySelector('#dDate').value;

Comment: And where do you do that?

Comment: At the very top of the JS, I managed to work it out. With your help and Ole. I am not used to using the console for debugging but when checking the values, for some reason even if I typed something it was being detected as blank. Changed it to this:

let inputName = document.querySelector('#txtName');
If(...|| inputName.value ==''|| ...)

And it worked, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Since your questions doesn't hold any of your html code, and since Im unsure if you javascript is the entire script, or if there is anything defined outside the scope of your functions, my answer is limited to the information you have provided.

> First off, since you are a new developer. You should first of, learn
>   how to use the developer tools of the browser you are using (most
>   browsers have them). There should be a console there, which will log
>   all the errors that occurs in your javascript. This is the most
>   efficient way to debug your code.

As someone have commented on your question here, the most likely error, is that the variables you are trying validate as blank or not, are undefined variables. Thus, they will never match ""

You should refer to the value of the input fields before you check them.

Lets say you have a input field:

```
<input name="test" type="text" id="testinput" />
```

Then you define the variable that refers to the value of this input, and check its value:

```
var testInput = document.getElementById('testinput').value
if( testInput === "" ) //Do something
```

Note, there are several methods to refer to a DOM-element in javascript, getElementById is just one of them. You should do some research, and choose the solution that fits you best

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you are storing the input value in those varialiables like `inputPassword` for example:

`const inputPassword = document.getElementById('myInput').value`

Your code should work as far as I can tell from what you have posted.
Hope it helps